# Why merge cells doesn't work with powershell

Tags: excel, powershell, merge

I have a powershell script to merge some cells in excel but doesn't work.
Can anyone help to check why? somehow the picture i loaded here are not accesible

seems it simply removed some data but didn't do the merge work.

```
$ExportFile = "I:\SCRIPT\IPCNewScript\Result.csv"

$xlShiftDown = -4121
$objExcel=New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
#$objExcel.Visible=$true
$objExcel.DisplayAlerts = FALSE

$WorkBook=$objExcel.Workbooks.Open($ExportFile)

$worksheet = $workbook.sheets.item("Result")

#Get row & column count
$objRange = $worksheet.UsedRange
$RowCount = $objRange.Rows.Count
$ColumnCount = $objRange.Columns.Count

for ( $i=3 ; $i -le 4; $i ++ ){
     $inc = 1
     $NexRow = $i + $inc
    for ( $j=1 ; $j -le 3; $j ++ ){

        $worksheet.Cells.Item($i,$j).Text
        $worksheet.Cells.Item($NexRow,$j).Text
        $MergeCells = $worksheet.Range($worksheet.Cells.Item($i,$j), $worksheet.Cells.Item($NexRow,$j))
        $MergeCells.Select() 
        $MergeCells.MergeCells = $true
        $MergeCells.Font.ColorIndex = 11 

        #$objRange.EntireColumn.AutoFit() | Out-Null
    }
}
$WorkBook.Save()
$objExcel.Quit()
```

[image]

Comment: @BenH  Thanks Ben i actually tried that one as well but still got the same result

Comment: i have changed $i ++ to be $i +=2. Works now!!

Answer (score 0):

i have changed $i ++ to be $i +=2. Works now!!